# Bootstrap Center and Right Alignment Issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to have a row in my code that has a centered date value and a edit link right aligned. I am not sure if this is best achieved within one column div and css or two divs (One = 11, other = 1), but I have tried the second approach and it doesn't center the date value within the row. Is there a better solution?

Current output:

[image: screenshot html]

Current html:

```
<div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-10">
            <p className="text-center"><b>12/25/18</b></p>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-1">
            <a href="/app/annotation/edit/id" className="annotation-kanban-card__head-edit-link"><span className="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Set the outermost `.row` to `position: relative` and set `EditAnnotation` to `position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0;`, then you should be able to fine tune from there.

Comment: I made an adjustment to the code to display what `EditAnnotation` is. Would you still recommend that solution?

Comment: I added a class, `.annotation-kanban-card__head-date` to the `.row` class and made it `position: relative` and added the css you proposed to `.annotation-kanban-card__head-edit-link`, but I still have a date that is not perfectly center on the row. It remained unchanged

Comment: I think so - I posted the recommendation as an answer. Obviously there are some unknowns, such as how the layout changes responsively, but I believe this is the cleanest approach, with minimal CSS.

Comment: Can you recreate as a code snippet here? or on jsfiddle?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention to switch to 12 cols for the p tag - glad this worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend this approach:

```
<div className="row">
    <div className="col-md-12 title-with-button">
        <p className="text-center"><b>12/25/18</b></p>
        <a href="/app/annotation/edit/id" className="annotation-kanban-card__head-edit-link"><span className="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

With the following CSS:

```
.title-with-button {
  position: relative;
}

.title-with-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

The CSS for this is fairly minimal, and depending on the length of the title should work responsively. Additionally, it removes some unnecessary div tags for cleaner HTML.